# Benchmarking VBA Code

Tags: excel, optimization, vba, benchmarking

What is considered the most accurate way to benchmark VBA code (in my case, I am testing code in Excel)? Are there any other techniques for benchmarking code besides the 2 below, and if so, what are the pros/cons of the method?

Here are 2 popular methods.

First: **Timer**

```vb
Sub TimerBenchmark()

Dim benchmark As Double
benchmark = Timer

'Do your code here

MsgBox Timer - benchmark

End Sub
```

And **Tick** (which I see argued as the most accurate):

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub TickBenchmark()

Dim Start As Long
Dim Finish As Long

Start = GetTickCount()

'Do your code here

Finish = GetTickCount()
MsgBox CStr((Finish - Start) / 1000)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following code uses a windows function that is more accurate than Excel. It is taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_MakingWorkbooksCalculateFaster. The same page also contains some great tips on improving performance in Excel 2007.

```
Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long

Function MicroTimer() As Double

  'Returns seconds.

  Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
  Static cyFrequency As Currency
  MicroTimer = 0

  ' Get frequency.
  If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency

  ' Get ticks.
  getTickCount cyTicks1                            

  ' Seconds
  If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency 
End Function
```

Comment: The author of that piece is a regular contributor to Stackoverflow. His own website has lots more great information about Excel and performance: http://www.decisionmodels.com/

Comment: Could you please summarize the code in the link in your answer in order to prevent link rot? Also, the supplied microtimer code doesn't seem to work on 64-bit Excel. Are there any alternatives for 64-bit users?

Comment: @StockB FWIW, add `PtrSafe` between `Declare` and `Function` for declaring API functions in 64-bit MS Office.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question. This is not really a full answer but this is too long to be posted as a comment.
What i use is this kind of procedure:

```
Option Explicit
Public Time As Double
Sub Chrono()
If Time = 0 Then
    Time = Now()
Else
    MsgBox "Total time :" & Application.Text(Now() - _
        Time, "mm:ss") & "."  'or whatever if not a msgbox
    Time = 0
End If
End Sub
```

That way, you can put your code wherever you want and only have to call it twice (for instance):

```
If C_DEBUG Then Call Chrono
```

At the beginning and at the end of the part of code you want to test.

Yet, i would say there is no real "accurate" method because it also depends on what is running on your computer. I'd say these methods would mostly help telling which code is *better* than another.

Answer (score 3):

Any measurement is going to be noisy, so if you want precision, repeat the measurement many times and average the result.

Answer (score 1):

[Professional Excel Development](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Excel-Development-Applications-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321508793) contains a dll utility `PerfMon` that I prefer, for its accuracy, and as it can be easily inserted throughout code with a couple of menu clicks

Answer (score 1):

As RonnieDickson answered the QueryPerformanceCounter function is the most accurate possible way to bench VBA code (when you don't want to use a dll, like brettdj suggested). I wrote a class that makes that function easy to use: only initialize the benchmark class + call the method in between your code. No need to write code for substracting times, re-initializing times and writing to debug for example.

```
Sub TimerBenchmark()

Dim bm As New cBenchmark

'Some code here
bm.Wait 0.0001
bm.TrackByName "Some code"

'Some more (time consuming) code here
bm.Wait 0.04
bm.TrackByName "Bottleneck code"

End Sub
```

Which would automatically print a readable table to the Immediate window:

```
IDnr  Name             Count  Sum of tics  Percentage  Time sum
0     Fast code            1       25.136       5,91%   2,51 ms
1     Bottleneck code      1      400.316      94,09%     40 ms
      TOTAL                2      425.452     100,00%     43 ms

Total time recorded:             43 ms
```

The class includes a .Wait function, which does the same as Application.Wait, but requires only an input in seconds, instead of a time value. It is used above to simulate some code.

https://github.com/jonadv/VBA-Benchmark

Comment: Seems to be very interesting; would be worth to add minimal methodical hints :+) @jonadv

Comment: What do you mean with methodical hints? That I should add the code of the written class to this comment?

Comment: Not the code, only a short description of the base logic (e.g. how you use API functions, why it's faster than other approaches, ...) and possibly some example features, too :-) @jonadv