# Select certain files with statement (combine files) VBA

Tags: vba

I got a code that merge two excel files to into one file.
without save.

I select first with a dialogWindow a SourceFolder,
I select then a TargetFolder with another dialogWindow.

I want instead of have two dialogwindows use One, to loop through a whole folder.

the filenames in the folder have this pattern see below:
but the names can be almost anything, there is one thing that make them as a pair.

Se follow Filenames so see the pattern:

```
TEST_Translation2_jeeves_sv.xls
TEST_Translation2_jeeves_sv_NoTrans.xls

TEST_Translation2_UCHPResourcesCommon_de.xls
TEST_Translation2_UCHPResourcesCommon_de_NoTrans.xls

TEST_Translation2_creditDocument_ar.xls
TEST_Translation2_creditDocument_ar_NoTrans.xls
```

if the select the first file of the examples:

I want now to merge the sheet from "TEST_Translation2_jeeves_sv_NoTrans.xls" to "TEST_Translation2_jeeves_sv.xls" and save the file (TEST_Translation2_jeeves_sv.xls)

the script need to loop through a whole folder.

Could someone help me to modify my code?

```
Sub Combinles_Step1()    
'Declare Variables
Dim WorkbookDestination As Workbook
Dim WorkbookSource As Workbook
Dim WorksheetSource As Worksheet
Dim FolderLocation As String
Dim strFilename As String


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select Source folder"
    If .Show = -1 Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        FolderLocation = .SelectedItems(1)

        'Dialog box to determine which files to use. Use ctrl+a to select all files in folder.
        SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
            filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)

        'Create a new workbook
        Set WorkbookDestination = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        strFilename = Dir(FolderLocation & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

        'Iterate for each file in folder
        If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub


        Do Until strFilename = ""

                Set WorkbookSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderLocation & "\" & strFilename)
                Set WorksheetSource = WorkbookSource.Worksheets(1)
                WorksheetSource.Copy After:=WorkbookDestination.Worksheets(WorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count)
                WorkbookSource.Close False
            strFilename = Dir()

        Loop
        WorkbookDestination.Worksheets(1).Delete

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay without getting into the code details:

```
Get the name of the file
Check to see if it contains the value "_NoTrans"
   If yes ignore it and move to the next
   Else the file name does not have the value "_NoTrans" then
      Take that name store it in a string variable
      Insert the "_NoTrans" value in front of the ".xls"
          Basically take the string value chop off the ".xls"
          Concatenate new string value + "_NoTrans" + ".xls"
              Note I do it in 3 pieces because "_NoTrans" should be a constant
              and ".xls" should also be a constant
Take the new filename variable and check if it exists
   If yes open it and work with it
   Else error
```

Hope that gets you moving the right direction

Okay not understanding -- would this not solve the situation? --  I mean all you have to do is apply VBA specific syntax to the above.

```
You are already getting the name of the file from what it looks like 
so it did not seem like you needed that explained.  

The next line is just a string compare function which you can find here
http://www.homeandlearn.org/text_and_excel_vba.html

The next 2 lines are simply an If / Else statement based on the results
of the string compare.

The next line pretty straight forward as well an assignment statement

The next 5 lines are just explaining a bit of simple string manipulations
InStr / Left / Dim y As String = "firstpart" + "middlepart" + "lastpart"
The above link will explain these if you do not understand them

The last 3 lines are just using the new name check to see if the file is
there which if you can open a file you should know how to check if a
file exists - yes/no?  if not go here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351249/vba-check-if-file-exists
```

So that should finish the deal -- or are you saying you do not want to do the simple coding yourself ??  I mean I took it as you were just stuck on the how not the syntax of the how.  With a bit of time I could easily translate the above into actual code but then I felt you could as well and I prefer to teach one to fish rather than just give you a fish.