# Save file without prompts or overwriting other files

Tags: excel, vba

I used this to get as far as I could, but it doesn't seem to fit my case well.  [VBA: Saving without overwriting existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492504/vba-saving-without-overwriting-existing-files)

What I'd like to do is save an initial file without a number associated with it, and any others that try to overwrite it with (1), (2), etc.  I also want this to be hands off, so if the file exists, I don't want the prompt to overwrite to appear, I'd just like it to decline and try to save as one of the next file names with the increasing numbers. I am only using this on a single sheet in a workbook

```
Dim wsDemo As Worksheet, i As Long, fName As String
Dim Savedir as String, curBook as String
Savedir = "C:\Users\Dio\Documents\Working Files\"
curBook = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set wsDemo = Workbooks(curBook & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Demo")

fName = "Popcorn"

    For i = 1 To 9
        If Len(Dir(Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ")" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv")) = 0 Then
            If Len(Dir(Savedir & fName & " Demo " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv")) = 0 Then
                wsDemo.SaveAs Savedir & fName & " Demo " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), 23
                Exit For
            Else
                wsDemo.SaveAs Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ") " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), 23
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right then you probably want this

```
Option Explicit

Sub saveAsSequence()
    Dim wsDemo As Worksheet, i As Long, fName As String
    Dim Savedir As String, curBook As String
    Savedir = "C:\Users\Dio\Documents\Working Files\"
    curBook = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    Set wsDemo = Workbooks(curBook & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Demo")
    
    fName = "Popcorn"
    
    Dim filename As String
    filename = Savedir & fName & " Demo " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
        
    Do
        If FileExists(filename) Then
            i = i + 1
            filename = Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ") " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
        Else
            wsDemo.SaveAs filename, 23
            Exit Do
        End If
        
    Loop Until i > 1000 ' "Safe" Exit not to create an endless loop
    
End Sub


Function FileExists(ByVal file As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = False
    FileExists = Dir(file) <> ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not checking whether the file exists without a number, it jumped straight into checking whether the file exists with 1-9. I have added a test for that outside of the loop.

The part of your code that saves the file without a number should be moved up to the new test outside of the loop.

`curBook` is not needed, use `ActiveWorkbook` instead

See if this works as intended:

```
Sub save_incr()

Dim wsDemo As Worksheet, i As Long, fName As String
Dim Savedir As String, curBook As String
Savedir = "C:\Users\Dio\Documents\Working Files\"
'curBook = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set wsDemo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Demo")

fName = "Popcorn"

'Check if initial file without a number exists
If Len(Dir(Savedir & fName & " Demo " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv")) = 0 Then
    
    wsDemo.SaveAs Savedir & fName & " Demo " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), 23

Else
    
    'Loop through 1 to 9, check if file exists
    For i = 1 To 9
        If Len(Dir(Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ") " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv")) = 0 Then
            If Len(Dir(Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ") " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv")) = 0 Then
                wsDemo.SaveAs Savedir & fName & " Demo " & "(" & i & ") " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), 23
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a reusable function:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 5
        PutContent NextSequence("C:\Temp\VBA\dump\Demo sequence<seq>.txt"), "Testing"
    Next n
End Sub

'Return the next unused file name given a path with "<seq>" as a placeholder
'  Start by replacing the placeholder with empty string, then incrment to "(2)", "(3)" etc
Function NextSequence(fPath As String)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Do
        NextSequence = Replace(fPath, "<seq>", IIf(i = 1, "", " (" & i & ")"))
        i = i + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop While Len(Dir(NextSequence)) > 0
End Function

'write some content to a file
Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 2, True).Write content
End Sub
```