# Saving attachments results in memory errors

Tags: vba, memory, outlook

I need to search through 9,000 emails and save the attachments with a certain timestamp (these are security camera feeds).

The code works on a small number of emails, but after about 20 the processing in Outlook appears to speed up significantly (attachments stop saving) and then Outlook hangs with a memory error.

My guess is the save step is not completed before the script moves to the next email in the target folder and therefore the backlog of saves becomes too large for Outlook.

```vb
' this function grabs the timestamp from the email body
'  to use as the file rename on save in the following public sub

Private Function GetName(olItem As MailItem) As String
    Const strFind As String = "Exact Submission Timestamp: "

    Dim olInsp As Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    Dim strDate As String
    With olItem
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(strFind)
                oRng.Collapse 0
                oRng.End = oRng.End + 23
                strDate = oRng.Text
                strDate = Replace(strDate, Chr(58), Chr(95))
                GetName = strDate & ".jpg"
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk24(MItem As outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim strFname As String
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\xxxxx\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        If oAttachment.FileName Like "*.jpg" Then
            strFname = GetName(MItem)
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & strFname
            Set oAttachment = Nothing
            Set MItem = Nothing
        End If
    Next oAttachment
```

Comment: What is your code that loops through the items?

Comment: Post full code please

Comment: That is the full code. Script is initiated from a Outlook rule. There is an end sub missing from the bottom

Comment: The outlook rule initiates the script on incoming mail. However, when I run it from manually against a mailbox folder i get the memory overload.

Comment: You are using methods with which I am not familiar so this is a guess.  Memory failures are normally caused by each repeat of a loop creating something and then not deleting it.  I suggest closing the `Inspector` before clearing the reference to it.

Comment: In function `GetName` you have a `Do` loop but, since the loop contains `Exit Do`, the loop is only executed once.  My understanding of this code is that it finds string “Exact Submission Timestamp:” and then extract the text immediately following which is assumed to a date.  The colons in the date are replaced by underlines.  Finally, the date is suffixed with “.jpg” and returned to the calling routine.  This could all have been done with VBA.  I do not see the benefits gained by using Word that would justify the overheads.

Comment: In sub `SaveAttachmentsToDisk24` you loop looking for every attachment with an extension of “jpg”.  Each such attachment is saved with the name returned by `GetName`.  If an email has more than one jpg attachment, the routine will attempt to save them all with the same name. I am not sure why you set the `MailItem` to Nothing in the middle of the loop.  I do not believe a sub-routine should destroy a parameter; to me it’s a hidden side-effect which can be nightmare to debug.

Comment: Your code design to run on single item, can you post a example data of your email?

Answer (score 0):

There are other possibilities but my belief is that the memory errors are the result of creating Word objects and then not closing them.  Om3r asked for more information but you ignored his requests making it impossible to provide a definitive answer.  However, I wanted to prove it was possible to extract attachments from a large number of emails without problems so I have made some guesses.

I understand why you need a routine that will scan your Inbox for the backlog of 8,000 camera feed emails.  I do not understand why you want to use an event to monitor your Inbox as well.  I cannot believe this is a time critical task.  Why not just run the scan once or twice a day?  However, the routine I have coded could be adapted to create a macro to be called by an event routine.  My current code relies of global variables which you will have to change to local variables.  I am not a fan of global variables but I did not want to create a folder reference for every call of the inner routine and the parameter list for a macro that might be called by an event routine is fixed.

To test the code I planned to create, I first generated 790 emails to myself that matched (I hope) your camera feed emails.  I had planned to create more but I think my ISP has classified me as a spammer, or perhaps a flamer, and it would not let me send any more.  The body of these emails looked like:

```
xxx Preamble xxx ‹cr›‹lf›|
Exact Submission Timestamp: 2019-02-22 15:00:00 ‹cr›‹lf›|
xxx Postamble xxx ‹cr›‹lf›|
```

Your code requires the string “Exact Submission Timestamp:” followed by a date which you use as a file name.  I have assumed that date in in a format that VBA can recognise as a date and I have assumed the date is ended by a standard Windows newline (carriage return, line feed).  The second assumption would be easy to change.  I have a routine that will accept many more date formats than VBA’s `CDate` which I can provide if necessary.

Each email has a different date and time between November, 2018 and February, 2019.

I would never save 8,000 files in a single disc folder.  Even with a few hundred files in a folder, it becomes difficult to find the one you want.  My root folder is “C:\DataArea\Test” but you can easily change that.  Given the timestamp in my example email, my routine would check for folder “C:\DataArea\Test\2019” then “C:\DataArea\Test\2019\02” and finally “C:\DataArea\Test\2019\02\22”.  If a folder did not exist, it would be created.  The attachment is then saved in the inner folder.  My code could easily be adapted to save files at the month level or the hour level depending on how many of these files you get per month, day or hour.

My routine checks every email in Inbox for the string “Exact Submission Timestamp:” followed by a date.  If it finds those, it checks for an attachment with an extension of JPG.  If the email passes all these tests, the attachment is saved in the appropriate disc folder and the email is moved from Outlook folder “Inbox” to “CameraFeeds1”.  The reasons for moving the email are: (1) it clears the Inbox and (2) you can rerun the routine as often as you wish without finding an already processed email.  I named the destination folder “CameraFeeds1” because you wrote that you wanted to do some more work on these emails.  I thought you could move the emails to folder “CameraFeeds2” once you had completed this further work.

I assumed processing 790 or 8,000 emails would take a long time.  In my test, the duration was not as bad as I expected; 790 emails took about one and a half minutes.  However, I created a user form to show progress.  I cannot include the form in my answer so you will have to create your own.  Mine looks like:

[image: Appearance of user form]

The appearance is not important.  What is important is the name of the form and the four controls on the form:

- Form name: frmSaveCameraFeeds
- TextBox name: txtCountCrnt
- TextBox name: txtCountMax
- CommandButton name: cmdStart
- CommandButton name: cmdStop

If you run the macro `StartSaveCameraFeeds` it will load this form.  Click [Start] to start the save process.  You can let the macro run until it has checked every email in the Inbox or you can click [Stop] at any time.  The stop button is not as important as I feared.  I thought the routine might take hours but that was not the case.

You don’t report where your 8,000 emails are.  I have an Inbox per account plus the default Inbox which I only use for testing.  I moved the 790 test emails to the default Inbox and used `GetDefaultFolder` to reference it.  I assume you know how to reference another folder if necessary.  Note I use `Session` instead of a name space.  These two methods are supposed to be equivalent but I always use `Session` because it is simpler and because I once had a failure with a name space that I could not diagnose.  I reference folder “CameraFeeds1” relative to the Inbox.

You will have to adjust my code at least partially.  For the minimum changes, do the following:

Create a new module and copy this code into it:

```
Option Explicit

  Public Const Marker As String = "Exact Submission Timestamp: "
  Public Const RootSave As String = "C:\DataArea\Test"

  Public FldrIn As Outlook.Folder
  Public FldrOut As Outlook.Folder 
Sub StartSaveCameraFeeds()

  ' Reference outlook folders then pass control to frmSaveCameraFeeds

  Set FldrIn = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set FldrOut = FldrIn.Parent.Folders("CameraFeeds1")

  Load frmSaveCameraFeeds
  With frmSaveCameraFeeds
    .Caption = "Saving jpg files from Camera feed emails"
    .txtCountCrnt = 0
    .txtCountMax = FldrIn.Items.Count
    .Show vbModal
  End With

  ' Form unloaded by cmdStop within form

  Set FldrIn = Nothing
  Set FldrOut = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub SaveCameraFeed(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem)

  ' Checks a single mail item to be a "camera feed" email.  If the mail item is
  ' a "camera feed" email, it saves the JPG file using the date within the
  ' email body as the file name.  If the mail item is not a "camera feed"
  ' email, it does nothing.

  ' To be a camera feed mail item:
  '  * The text body must contain a string of the form: "xxxyyyy" & vbCr & vbLf
  '    where "xxx" matches the public constant Marker and "yyy" is recognised
  '    by VBA as a date
  '  * It must have an attachment with an extension of "JPG" or "jpg".

  ' If the mail item is a camera feed email:
  '  * In "yyy" any colons are replaced by understores.
  '  * The JPG attachment is saved with the name yyy & ".jpg"

  Dim DateCrnt As Date
  Dim DateStr As String
  Dim DayCrnt As String
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim MonthCrnt As String
  Dim PathFileName As String
  Dim PosEnd As Long
  Dim PosStart As Long
  Dim SomethingToSave As Boolean
  Dim YearCrnt As String

  SomethingToSave = False   ' Assume no JPG to save until find otherwise
  With ItemCrnt
    PosStart = InStr(1, .Body, Marker)
    If PosStart > 0 Then
      PosStart = PosStart + Len(Marker)
      PosEnd = InStr(PosStart, .Body, vbCr & vbLf)
      DateStr = Mid$(.Body, PosStart, PosEnd - PosStart)
      If IsDate(DateStr) Then
        DateCrnt = DateStr
        For InxA = 1 To .Attachments.Count
          If LCase(Right$(.Attachments(InxA).Filename, 4)) = ".jpg" Then
            SomethingToSave = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End If
    End If

    If SomethingToSave Then
      DateStr = Replace(DateStr, ":", "_")
      YearCrnt = Year(DateCrnt)
      MonthCrnt = Month(DateCrnt)
      DayCrnt = Day(DateCrnt)
      Call CreateDiscFldrIfItDoesntExist(RootSave, YearCrnt, MonthCrnt, DayCrnt)
      PathFileName = RootSave & "\" & YearCrnt & "\" & MonthCrnt & "\" & DayCrnt & _
                     "\" & Trim(DateStr) & ".jpg"
      .Attachments(InxA).SaveAsFile PathFileName
      .Move FldrOut
    End If

  End With

End Sub
Public Sub CreateDiscFldrIfItDoesntExist(ByVal Root As String, _
                                         ParamArray SubFldrs() As Variant)

  ' If a specified disk folder (not an Outlook folder) does not exist, create it.

  ' Root      A disk folder which must exist and for which the user
  '           must have write permission.
  ' SubFldrs  A list of sub-folders required within folder Root.

  ' Example call: CreateDiscFldrsIfNecessary("C:\DataArea", "Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc")
  ' Result: Folder "C:\DataArea\Aaa\Bbb\Ccc" will be created if it does not already exist.

  ' Note: MkDir("C:\DataArea\Aaa\Bbb\Ccc") fails unless folder "C:\DataArea\Aaa\Bbb" exists.

  Dim Filename As String
  Dim Fldrname As String
  Dim InxSF As Long

  Fldrname = Root

  For InxSF = LBound(SubFldrs) To UBound(SubFldrs)

    Fldrname = Fldrname & "\" & SubFldrs(InxSF)
    If Not PathExists(Fldrname) Then
      Call MkDir(Fldrname)
    End If

  Next

End Sub     
Public Function PathExists(ByVal Pathname As String) As Boolean

  ' Returns True if path exists

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore
  ' Based on code written by iDevlop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28237845/973283

  On Error Resume Next
  PathExists = ((GetAttr(Pathname) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)
  On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

I must warn you that I have modules full of standard routines that I use all the time.  I believe I have included all the standard routines used by the code I have written for you.  If the code fails because a sub or function is missing, post a comment and I will apologise and add the missing macro to my code.

Near the top of the above code is `Public Const RootSave As String = "C:\DataArea\Test"`.  You will have to change this to reference your root folder.

The first statement of `Sub StartSaveCameraFeeds()` is `Set FldrIn = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`.  Amend this as necessary if the emails are not in the default Inbox.

In the body of `Sub StartSaveCameraFeeds()` you will find `PosEnd = InStr(PosStart, .Body, vbCr & vbLf)`.  If the date string is not ended by a standard Windows’ newline, amend this statement as necessary.

Create a user form.  Add two TextBoxes and two CommandButtons.  Name them as defined above.  Copy the code below to the code area of the form:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdStart_Click()

  ' Call SaveCameraFeed for every MailItem in FldrIn

  Dim CountMax As Long
  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim MailItemCrnt As MailItem

  With FldrIn

    CountMax = FldrIn.Items.Count

    For InxI = CountMax To 1 Step -1

      If .Items(InxI).Class = olMail Then
        Set MailItemCrnt = .Items(InxI)
        Call SaveCameraFeed(MailItemCrnt)
        Set MailItemCrnt = Nothing
      End If
      txtCountCrnt = CountMax - InxI + 1
      DoEvents

    Next

  End With

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub cmdStop_Click()

  Unload Me

End Sub
```

The form code should not need amendment.

As I have already written, this code processed 790 camera feed emails in about one and a half minutes.  I coded a further routine that checked that for every email the date matched the name of a jpg file.  I could include this routine in my answer if you would like to perform the same check.