# Detect new mail then extract, unzip and rename attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive 4 weekly emails from 3 different senders.

Emails 1 and 2 are from the same sender and can be recognized through VBA. These emails contain zip files, where each zip file has one .csv file.

Emails 3 and 4 can also be recognized by VBA and the attachments are Excel sheets (.xlsx).

I want to extract and unzip (where needed) and save these 4 files in a folder as; `email1.report`, `email2.report` etc.
Then make a copy of these 4 files in a different folder for each file and rename like; "Today's date".email1.report.csv etc.

I want to combine these steps in a single code and to replace the email1.report, email2.report etc., files without a prompt asking "do you want to replace the files? Yes, No?"

Is it possible to detect the new weekly emails and do this automatically?

The code I use to unzip and save:

```
Else
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "zip" Then
            FileNameFolder = "C:\Users\..."
            FileName = FileNameFolder & Left(Atmt.FileName, (InStr(1, Atmt.FileName, ".zip") - 1)) & ".txt"
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName

            FileNameT = FileNameFolder & Atmt.FileName

            Name FileName As FileNameT

            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((FileNameT)).Items

            Kill FileNameT

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt
    'item.Close
End If
```

Comment: Your current question is too broad to answer.  Do you want your Inbox monitored for these emails?  Do you want to run a macro each morning that looks for this email?  What does "save a copy with a date" mean?  What does "Same case with just an excel file" mean?  " I would like to replace the old file without asking a question."  Which old file?  Which unzip package do you use?  Does it have a command line interface?  What you seek is almost certainly possible.  Have you tried creating a macro using code you found here or elsewhere?

Comment: Okay what I wrote is certainly not clear. I will try to rewrite and make it more easy to understand.

Comment: I receive 4 weekly mails with attachments, 2 zip files and 2 excel files. For the zipped files, I want to extract and save to a specified folder the .csv files. Then make a renamed copy of the .csv files to another folder. Same logic applies for the excel files as well, extract and save to a specified folder and then make a renamed copy to another folder. I would like one code for all these steps, is it possible? Hope it makes more sense now? :)

Comment: You need to add this extra detail to your question.  Comments are limited to 500 characters and have only basic formatting.  A complete question would be much easier to understand than a vague question plus comments.

Comment: How are these four emails recognised?  Are they from a particular sender? Do they have a particular subject?  Could an Outlook rule recognise them or must you as a human identify them?  Having identified one of these emails, saving attachments is easy.  Creating a second copy of a file with a new name in a different folder is easy.

Comment: I use WinZip which has a command line interface.  I have not unzipped files with VBA for some years since I use VB for archiving and restoring files.  I have recently discovered how to unzip from VBA using 7-Zip which was tricky.  What zip-unzip package do you use?  Does it have a command line interface?  Do you know that CLI or are you hoping someone here knows it?

Comment: I just edited the original post, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I won't develop the code for your specific problem, but I recently wrote something similar. Maybe you can go from here by altering to your criteria etc.

In my case I had two e-mails incoming shortly after another, within 60 seconds. Both mails had "FP" in their subject and a .pdf-attachment. The task was to concatenate these attachments using the installed PDF24, which luckily offers a shell command for this.
This was the code, placed in the "ThisOutlookSession" of the Outlook VBA project explorer.

```
Public btAttachmentMails As Byte
Public dtArrivalStamp As Date
Public strPathFirstMailAttachment As String
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDocumentsFolder As String
    strDocumentsFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    strPathFirstMailAttachment = strDocumentsFolder & "\attachment_mail1.pdf"

    If Item.Subject Like "FP*" Then

        If btAttachmentMails = 0 Then
            'first mail -> save attachment and set counter to 1
            btAttachmentMails = 1
            dtArrivalStamp = Time

            For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
                If InStr(Item.Attachments.Item(i).DisplayName, ".PDF") > 0 Then
                    Item.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strPathFirstMailAttachment
                End If
            Next i

        ElseIf btAttachmentMails = 1 Then
            Dim dtNow As Date: dtNow = Time

            If TimeDiff(dtArrivalStamp, dtNow) <= 60 Then
            'second mail within 60 seconds with subject containing "FP" -> save attachment and concatenate both via pdf24, then delete both files

                'save attachment of second mail
                Dim strPathSecondMailAttachment As String
                strPathSecondMailAttachment = strDocumentsFolder & "\attachment_mail2.pdf"

                For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
                    If InStr(Item.Attachments.Item(i).DisplayName, ".PDF") > 0 Then
                        Item.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strPathSecondMailAttachment
                    End If
                Next i

                'concatenate pdf documents via pdf24 shell
                Dim strOutputPath As String
                strOutputPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date) & "_Wartungsplan_" & Replace(CStr(Time), ":", "-") & ".PDF"
                Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF24\pdf24-DocTool.exe"" -join -profile ""default/good"" -outputFile " & strOutputPath & " " & strPathFirstMailAttachment & " " & strPathSecondMailAttachment)

                'inform user
                MsgBox ("Files have been successfully concatenated. You can find the combined file on your desktop.")

                'reset status, delete temporary documents
                btAttachmentMails = 0
                If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").fileexists(strPathFirstMailAttachment) Then Kill strPathFirstMailAttachment
                If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").fileexists(strPathSecondMailAttachment) Then Kill strPathSecondMailAttachment

            Else
            'second mail did not arrive within 60 seconds -> treat as first mail
            'save new arrival time and overwrite old firstMailAttachment with this one

                dtArrivalStamp = Time

                For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
                    If InStr(Item.Attachments.Item(i).DisplayName, ".PDF") > 0 Then
                        Item.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strPathFirstMailAttachment 'overwrites existing file
                    End If
                Next i

            End If

        End If

    End If

End If

ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & " - please contact XY"
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub

Function TimeDiff(StartTime As Date, StopTime As Date)
    TimeDiff = Abs(StopTime - StartTime) * 86400
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks as well, much appreciated! I will take a look and adjust the code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

cr44sh has posted an answer while I was creating mine.  He has recommended using a new item event while I have recommended using a rule.  I prefer rules but you can choose which ever approach you favour.

It is impossible to fully answer your question but I believe I can give enough help for you to construct the macros you need yourself.

You say that these emails can be identified with VBA.  That suggests the best approach is an Outlook rule which uses the “run a script” option where “run a script” means “run a macro”.  I will discuss the rule later but first you need the macros that will be run.

You will need two macros like this:

```
Public Sub Type1Email(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem)
  ' Relevant code
End Sub
Public Sub Type2Email(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem)
  ' Relevant code
End Sub
```

I am sure you can create better names for these macros.  I have read that macros to be run by a rule must be in `ThisOutlookSession`.  In my experience, they can be in an ordinary module providing they are declared as `Public`.  I only use `ThisOutlookSession` for code that has to be in that code area.  If code can be in a module, that is where I place it.  I suggest creating a new module which will be named Module1 or Module2.  Use function key <kbd>F4</kbd> to access its properties and rename it as “ModRuleMacros” or similar.  Giving modules meaningful names makes it so much easier to find the code you want to look at today.

Although the aim is to create a macro to be run by a rule, you need a way of testing the macro.  If you have some of these emails saved somewhere, you can activate the rule by moving one of those emails to Inbox.  However, I generally find it easier to use a macro like this:

```
Sub TestType1Email()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Pleaase select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call Type1Email(ItemCrnt)
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

To use this macro, you select one or more Type1 emails and then run macro `TestType1Email`.  This macro will pass the selected emails, one at a time, to the macro `Type1Email`.  This will allow you to single step through macro `Type1Email` and ensure that it works to your entire satisfaction.  I find this to be the easier method of testing a new Outlook macro.

It may be helpful to check what a rule can do for you.  Select one of these emails and then click on <kbd>Rules</kbd>, which is in the middle of the Home tab, and then <kbd>Create rule …</kbd>.  Selecting one of these emails means the first window is filled out with some options.  Click <kbd>Advanced options …</kbd>.  The new window lists all the options for selecting an email.  Are all the options you need to select a type 1 or a type 2 email listed?  The list is comprehensive but not complete.  For example, you cannot select by the presence of attachments.  Identify the options you can use and identify the options you need that are missing.  Click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> twice to exist from rule creation.

You will need include code for any missing options in your macro.

Your question implies you have all the code you need for processing the emails except for suppressing the replace question.  You need to check if there is an existing file before creating the new file.  This is the routine that I use to check if a file exists:

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal PathName As String, ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean

  ' Returns True if file exists.  Assumes path already tested.

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore
  ' Based on code written by iDevlop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28237845/973283

  ' Ensure only one "\" between path and filename
  If Right$(PathName, 1) <> "\" Then
    PathName = PathName & "\"
  End If
  If Left$(FileName, 1) = "\" Then
    FileName = Mid$(FileName, 2)
  End If

  FileExists = False
  On Error Resume Next
  FileExists = ((GetAttr(PathName & FileName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
  On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

If the file exists, you can:

- Use VBA statement `Kill` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/kill-statement) to delete the old file.
- Use VBA statement Name (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement)  to move the old file to another folder or rename it perhaps by adding a date at the beginning of the name.

I favour the second option because I do not like deleting a file until I am really, really sure I will not need it again.  I saw too many situations during my career where a file deleted as no longer needed was found to be incorrectly or incompletely processed a few months later.

Once you have fully tested the macros, you can create the rules to execute them.  For each type of email:

- Select an email of the required type.
- Click on <kbd>Rules</kbd> and then <kbd>Create rule …</kbd>.
- Tick any relevant boxes on the first window.
- Click <kbd>Advanced options …</kbd>.
- Tick all relevant boxes on the second window.
- Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
- Tick the box against “Run a script”.
- Click <kbd>a script</kbd>.
- You will be shown a list of all the macros that can be run from a rule.  Select the required macro.
- Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
- Tick the box against any appropriate exceptions and enter any additional information required.
- Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
- Name the rule.  Tick “run this rule against any messages already in Inbox” if required.  Review the rule and edit if necessary.
- Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

I hope the above is enough to plug the holes in your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, much appreciated! I will take a look and let you know if it works! Wish I could repay somehow