# VBA to skip attaching files to email when file is not found in the folder, but attach if found

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with VBA to skip attaching file if file is not found in the folder
i have tried adding the "if then" but no luck there. would someone please be able to help here
I want the vba to skip if file is not found and attach other files that are found only.

```
With objEmail
.To = 
.Cc = 
.Subject = 
'.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
.HTMLBody = StrBody2 & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & StrBody3 & "<br>" & .HTMLBody

 pdfFileName1 = Dir(pdfFolderPath1 & "file.pdf")
 pdfFileName5 = Dir(pdfFolderPath4 & "file2.pdf")
 pdfFileName6 = Dir(pdfFolderPath4 & "file3.pdf")
 pdfFileName2 = Dir(pdfFolderPath2 & "file4.pdf")
 pdfFileName3 = Dir(pdfFolderPath3 & "file5.pdf")
 pdfFileName4 = Dir(pdfFolderPath3 & "file6.pdf")
       
            pdfFilePath1 = pdfFolderPath1 & pdfFileName1
            pdfFilePath2 = pdfFolderPath2 & pdfFileName2
            pdfFilePath3 = pdfFolderPath3 & pdfFileName3
            pdfFilePath4 = pdfFolderPath3 & pdfFileName4
            pdfFilePath5 = pdfFolderPath4 & pdfFileName5
            pdfFilePath5 = pdfFolderPath4 & pdfFileName6
                
                .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath1, , , pdfFileName1
           
                 .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath2, , , pdfFileName2
            
              pdfFileName = Dir
            
        
                .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath3, , , pdfFileName3
                .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath4, , , pdfFileName4
                .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath5, , , pdfFileName5
                .Attachments.Add pdfFilePath5, , , pdfFileName6
                    
       
.Display ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.

End With
With Application

End Sub
```

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/16351249/16578424 - there are several methods described how to check if a file exists

Answer (score 3):

In programming, you don't need "luck" - you need to be precise.

With `Dir`, you can check if a file exists. If not, `Dir` returns the empty string and you simply omit this file.

I would suggest you add a small subroutine for checking and attaching a file so that the code that creates the mail can be simplified. Don't know if you use early or late binding, so I go with late binding:

```
Sub AddFileAsAttachment(eMail As Object, path As String, filename As String)
    Dim fullName As String
    If Right(path, 1) = "\" Then
        fullName = path & filename
    Else
        fullName = path & "\" & filename
    End If
    If Dir(fullName) = "" Then Exit Sub   ' File not found
    eMail.Attachments.Add fullName, , , filename
End Sub
```

...and in your code to create the mail (not sure about your path and filenames, maybe you have to adapt that):

```
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath1, "file.pdf"
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath4, "file2.pdf"
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath4, "file3.pdf"
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath2, "file4.pdf"
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath3, "file5.pdf"
AddFileAsAttachment objMail, pdfFolderPath3, "file6.pdf"
.Display
```