# Path not found due to different folder structure for each user

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code which finds an email template through a file path and pre-fills the email based on cells within the spreadsheet. It also finds the email attachment based on the name of the attachment in the cell and finds that within the file path.

This worked locally, however it is now being used by colleagues and all have different file path accessed as below:

```
Me: G:\Group\Data\Business\Call\Excel\Email.oft
Colleague 1: G:\Data\Business\Call\Excel\Email.oft
Colleague 2: G:\Business\Call\Excel\Email.oft
```

We can all view and click on the email template.

When inserting the file path into the VBA code, if I put my file path, they cannot access it and if I put their file path, I cannot access it with the error

> Path not found

I assume as there is a “step” missing in the path.

How can I bypass the file path restrictions?

I tried `\..\` to replace the missing paths but does not work/fill the gap.

The primary Excel spreadsheet is opened via a SharePoint site so cannot use `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

```vb
Sub Send_email_fromtemplate()
Dim edress As String
Dim subj, name As String
Dim filename As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim attachment As String
Dim r As Long
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim customername As String

r = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) not equal to  ""
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'call your template
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("G:\Group\Data\Business\Call\Excel\Email.oft")
    outlookmailitem.Display
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
    'deifine your path for the attachment
    path = "G:\Group\Data\Business\Call\Excel\"
    edress = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1)
    name = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
    subj = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3)
    filename = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4)
    attachment = path + filename
    With outlookmailitem
        .To = edress
        .cc = ""
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = subj
        myAttachments.Add (attachment)
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="{{Placeholder for Name}}")
                oRng.Text = name
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
        Set xInspect = outlookmailitem.GetInspector
  
       .Display
        '.send
    End With
    'clear your email address
    edress = ""
    r = r + 1
Loop
'clear your fields
Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are around 20 users but have no way of determining all their file paths. Also I want to make it accessible for one-off users.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you could detect with code who is executing the code with [Environ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function) and then make conditionals paths based on result. Something like `If Environ("Username")=Me then Path1 Elseif Environ("Username")=User1 then Path2...` and so on.

Comment: Thank you. There are actually around 20 users (sorry, should’ve mentioned that) but have no way of determining all their file paths. Also want to make it accessible for new once-off users, so whoever uses the tool created can access its functions.

Comment: Then your only option would be handling errors. You need to start with one path, try it, if error then try path2 if error try path3 and so on... You'll need the paths anyways if there is no a common one but trying each one of them can be time consuming.... You'll need to check if file exists in each path and select one when true. check [VBA check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351249/vba-check-if-file-exists)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unable to apply and if error or if else then to my code no matter how hard I try to manipulate it. I can’t even make it search for the path and object separately…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the server path rather than the local path.  This shouldn't be different no matter what drive letter you're mapped to.

`.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\ServerName\Darren Bartrup-Cook\Test\OL_Template.oft")`

One way to find the path (other options are no doubt available):

- Press Windows Key + R to open the *Run* dialog box.
- Type "*cmd*" and click OK.
- In the Command Prompt window enter "*net use*" and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do if file paths are different  - you can either prompt the user for the file path or instruct them to ensure the file path is exactly what your code expects.

To prompt a user for a folder, you can use the `Shell.Application` object's `BrowseForFolder` method. Below is a VBScript example that prompts the user to select a folder and then displays the selected path:

```
Dim objShell, objFolder, strFolderPath

' Create the Shell Application object
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

' Prompt the user to select a folder
' 0 is the root folder type, e.g., Desktop
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder:", 0)

' Check if a folder was selected
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    strFolderPath = objFolder.Self.Path
    MsgBox "You selected the folder: " & strFolderPath
Else
    MsgBox "No folder was selected."
End If

' Clean up
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
```

Comment: Hm. Is there a way to click the link, which to open file explorer for the user to locate it themselves? There are variables within the sheet, but this could work…

Comment: See the updated answer above.